# TikZ and other figures in documents meant for multiple paper sizes

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, paper-size

Sometimes scientific papers are sent to multiple journals with very varying paper sizes. Usually, changing from one to another, I simply cross my fingers that TikZ figures still fit, and rescale PDF figures.

I'm now looking to "do the right thing" from the beginning, and I wonder: Is it even worth it to produce plots in a range of sizes, and define macros to pick different sizes for different versions of the document, or is this all a losing battle?

Comment: I personally would not produce plots in different range of sizes. You will have to produce a camera-ready version of your manuscript anyways, once the text is finished. And how many times do you submit the same final mansucript to different journals?

Comment: Not many - it's just that the programmer in me feels it's so nice to be able to make multiple presentations over the same underlying data in a automated way.

Comment: You can always use standalone to create a "full size" version of the figure, then use \includegraphics to scale it.

Comment: @JohnKormylo: Good point. Maybe that's a more pragmatic way of doing it.